# Reload top window from a popup window opened from colorbox(in top window)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, colorbox

I am opening a colorbox in my page.
In the colorbox iframe page, i have a link, that opens a popup window (window.open).

Now i want to reload the top window page that opened the colorbox, from the popup window.

I have tried the following code in my popup window, but it does not work:

```
echo '<script>window.top.location.href="test.php"; window.close();</script>';
```

Is it possible to control the top most window from the popup window that was opened from the colorbox (which was opened from the top window) ?

Answer (score 2):

The page that opened the popup window is referred to as `opener`, so

```
window.opener.location.href = 'test.php'; 
window.close();
```

If the opener window is an iframe itself, you need to follow the chain:

```
window.opener.top.location.href = 'test.php';
```

Comment: I tried this code in the popup window.. but even the popup window is not close... and it gives error: NS_ERROR_DOM_PROP_ACCESS_DENIED: Access to property denied.

Comment: @dskanth I forgot to mention that the domain of the popup and opener must be the same.

Comment: Yes, both the domains are same: my localhost

Comment: @dskanth I've updated the answer to refer to the `location` object more explicitly; not sure why that would be a problem.

Comment: This code works seamlessly when the popup is opened from the top window... but when the popup is opened from a colorbox iframe in the top window, this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Iframes are handled a little different.  Does this work for you?

```
<script>parent.$.colorbox.close(); parent.location.href="test.php";</script>
```

Although, if you are changing the location of the parent document, you don't really need to close colorbox too.